# Recuperar dados do localStorage para uma lista

Tags: ionic, ionic3, ionic2, localstorage

Bom dia, estou desenvolvendo um app com o ionic 3 e tenho a seguinte situação :

Estou gravando uma lista de produtos no localStorage, após isso, necessito em trazer os dados gravados, para uma lista de produtos, ou seja, cada item do vetor, cria uma coluna na lista. Código:

Grava no LocalStorage:

```
  localStorage.setItem("vetor", JSON.stringify(this.vetCarrinho));
```

Recupera do LocalStorage:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {

if (this.pedido.key) {
  let prod: any = localStorage.getItem('vetor').split(",");
  if (prod != null) {
    prod = JSON.parse(prod);
    if (this.vetCarrinho.indexOf(prod) === -1) {
        this.vetCarrinho.push(this.pedido.produto);
    }
  }
}
```

Html :

```
  <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let element of vetCarrinho"> 
          {{element}}    
          <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="deleteProduto(element)" item-end>
            <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
          </button>      
        </ion-item>     
       </ion-list>
```

A partir disso, ele joga TODOS os elemento em APENAS UMA COLUNA :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como procedo para que ele crie uma coluna cada elemento ?

Comment: Como está seu `vetCarrinho`?

Comment: [celular,celular]

Comment: ao meu ver seu código está correto, tem algum detalhe que não está renderizando corretamente.

Comment: Tentei usar o split, para separar por vírgula, mas não obtive sucesso. Editei a pergunta

Comment: Tenta assim pra ver: `let prod: any = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('vetor'));
  if (prod != null) {
   for(let i=0; i<prod.length; i++) {
      if (this.vetCarrinho.indexOf(prod[i]) === -1) {
        this.vetCarrinho.push(this.pedido.produto);
    }
}

  }`

Comment: Cara, antes de mandar pro firebase, eu estou passando: this.pedido.produto = this.vetCarrinho, será que pode ser isso o problema ?

Answer (score 0):

Fazer

```
  const prod = localStorage.getItem('vetor');
  if (prod != null) {
      this.vetCarrinho = JSON.parse(prod);
  }
```

não chega? :)

Atenção que sempre que fazer

```
localStorage.setItem("vetor", JSON.stringify(this.vetCarrinho));
```

Estás a escrever por cima de eventuais dados que estão guardados com a key 'vetor'